# WooCommerce Lightbox, Ordering and +/- buttons won't work

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, lightbox, orders

I am a webdesigners and I want to make a webshop with WooCommerce.
I use my own styles and everything is good, but a few things won't work.
The WooCommerce lightbox doesn't work, if you click on a image it goes to the page of the image and it doesn't open in a lightbox.

The WooCommerce ordering on the shop page doesn't work either, if you change the filter to date, the page doesn't refresh.

And last but not least on the product page I don't have plus and minus buttons, for example on the Canvas theme of WooThemes you have them ass well.
http://demo.woothemes.com/canvas/shop/flying-ninja/

Does anyone know who to solve this problem?

Greets,
Joren

P.S.
I come from the Netherlands, so if my English is bad, I apologise.

Comment: did you activate the lightbox plugin ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to update your woo-commerce plugin to latest version. After that add this code in your functions.php file and see the magic,

```
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
```